# Why is ds = p*dp*dΦ and not ds = dp*dΦ?

Tags: current

The problem I am having is with ds. I understand the two integral bounds, which are the radius and the 2pi boundary for the circle. It also makes sense with the units to integrate twice to eliminate the m^2 and get a current out. I just don't understand where the p comes from in the ds= p*dp*dΦ. If there is way that you could explain this very simply that would be nice. I just want enough information where I can get the ball rolling on my own and become more comfortable with these problems, thank you.

In a cylindrical conductor of radius 4 mm, the current density is J=5e^(-10*p) Amps/m^2.
Find the current through the conductor.

[image]

Comment: J seems constant to me .  Only if the current density varies as a function of the radius then it is necessary to integrate.

Comment: You mean integrating from 0 to the function of J? I kind of figured that, but why is there an extra rho in ds =p dpdΦ?

Comment: In a cylindrical metal wire, the free electrons do not have a concentration that varies with the radius of the wire but is constant, so the current density is also such and the current is given by the product density times the area of the wire section. So the question is incomprehensible unless it is clarified.

Comment: If the charge density is constant over time, then thanks to the continuity equation we have that the divergence of the current density in the conductor is zero. Since the current density is proportional to the longitudinal electric field via the conductivity constant and the field equal to the opposite of the potential gradient, the current density is equal to the opposite of the product of the conductivity times the potential gradient. If the conductivity is constant and the potential gradient is constant, then the current density is also constant.